# jquery add active class to a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Jquery reveal to show hide div with anchor tag i am trying to add class ('active') to `a` tag when i click on it to show hidden div then there should be 'active' class appear like Open/Close i have used `.addClass('active')` it work but when i again click on anchor the class="active" doesn't disappear.

here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slide_div").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show().addClass('active');

        $('.show_hide').click(function(){        
            $(".slide_div").slideToggle();
        });

    });
</script>

<a class="show_hide" href="#">Open/Close</a>
<div class="slide_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `$(".show_hide").toggleClass('active');`

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(".slide_div").slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J8WXP/)

Comment: but class not disappering when i click again on anchor to hide div.

Answer (score 4):

Use `toggleClass("active")` instead of `addClass('active')`

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. i just wanted to know how could be class remove when i click again on anchor to hide div.?